# Confirming something is a basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

I am brand new to topology and had some questions regarding topological bases.

I am currently working through Furstenburg's proof of the infinitude of primes. I am stuck trying to understand this:

Consider A defined in the following way:

$A(n,a) = \{a+nq : q\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Now consider $B$ defined in the following way:

$B=\{A(n,a):a,n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\neq 0  \}$

Now I know (because it says in the proof) that B is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ . Apparently the proof of this is very simple but I just don't see exactly what I am supposed to do to prove the following two conditions are true:

1) For each $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is at least one basis element containing $x$.

2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements, there is a third basis element containing $x$ that is in the intersection of the first 2 basis elements.

It is mostly this second part I am having trouble understanding. Again it seems very simple but if someone could just show what I need to do to prove that this is a basis, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what I meant

Comment: Done editing. Also, +1 for the question.

Comment: Note $A(n,a) = \bigcap_{p^k \| n} A(p^k,a)$. For any $n,m$ coprime and $a,b$ there exists $k,c$ such that $A(n,a) \cap A(m,b) = A(k,b)$ (chinese remainder theorem). For $n,m$ non coprime  use that $A(n,a) \cap A(n,b) = \emptyset$ if $n \nmid b -a$

Answer (score 1):

$A(0,1) =\mathbb{Z}$ so condition 1. is easy. (or $a \in A(a,q)$ for any $q$).

If $a_3 \in A(a_1,q_1) \cap A(a_2,q_2)$, then check that  $$a_3 \in A(a_3, \gcd(q_1, q_2)) \subseteq A(a_1,q_1) \cap A(a_2, q_2)$$

for the second condition.

Facts: $a_3 \in A(a_1, q_1)$ iff $A(a_3, q_1) = A(a_1, q_1)$, and $A(a,q_1) \cap A(a,q_2) = A(a, \gcd(q_1, q_2))$. So I think you have $=$ instead of $\subseteq$ above, even.

Comment: The topology is metrizable but not completely metrizable.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed it's homeomorphic to the rationals (regular (from zerodimensional),second countable and no isolated points).

Comment: This topology is the one used for the topological proof that the set P of primes is infinite.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know. $\{1,-1\} = \mathbb{Z}\setminus \cup_{p \in P} A(0,p)$ etc.